# Bug when switching to Rails 4.1 - `method_missing': undefined method `whitelist_attributes=' for ActiveRecord::Base:Class (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

When switching from Rails 4.0 to Rails 4.1 I am getting this error:

```
activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing': undefined method `whitelist_attributes=' for ActiveRecord::Base:Class (NoMethodError)
```

I am not using  `attr_accessible` or `attr_protected` anywhere on my app so I wonder why I have a problem.

When moving to Rails 4.0 I had already put on my application.rb:

config/application.rb:

```
config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = false
```

The full error log is:

```
/home/mathieu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing': undefined method `whitelist_attributes=' for ActiveRecord::Base:Class (NoMethodError)
    from /home/mathieu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:110:in `block (3 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
    from /home/mathieu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:109:in `each'
    from /home/mathieu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:109:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
    from /home/mathieu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
    from /home/mathieu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
    from /home/mathieu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:28:in `block in on_load'
    from /home/mathieu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `each'
    from /home/mathieu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `on_load'
    from /home/mathieu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:108:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
    from /home/mathieu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /home/mathieu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /home/mathieu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /home/mathieu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /home/mathieu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/mathieu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /home/mathieu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/mathieu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
    from /home/mathieu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/mathieu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
    from /home/mathieu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /home/mathieu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/application.rb:300:in `initialize!'
    from /home/mathieu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `public_send'
    from /home/mathieu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `method_missing'
    from /home/mathieu/rails_projects/app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/mathieu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /home/mathieu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
    from /home/mathieu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/mathieu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /home/mathieu/rails_projects/_app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /home/mathieu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from /home/mathieu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from /home/mathieu/rails_projects/app/config.ru:in `new'
    from /home/mathieu/rails_projects/app/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /home/mathieu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    from /home/mathieu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    from /home/mathieu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /home/mathieu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from /home/mathieu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
    from /home/mathieu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:50:in `app'
    from /home/mathieu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
    from /home/mathieu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:130:in `log_to_stdout'
    from /home/mathieu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:67:in `start'
    from /home/mathieu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
    from /home/mathieu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
    from /home/mathieu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
    from /home/mathieu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /home/mathieu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I'm really lost here as most people having bugs kind of related to mine suggest to use gem 'protected_attributes`but I don't want to use it as I don't have any`attr_accessible`nor`attr_protected`.

Any idea where this bug comes from ?

Comment: Rails 4 uses strong_params instead of attr_accessible. Read how to upgrade http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html

Comment: Remove the config setting `whitelist_attributes`.

Comment: I have the same type of issue but different error , can you please check the following link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29227079/issues-with-rails4-and-mongoid-on-production-mode

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can safely remove 
**config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = false**

From your app config file.

And remove all white_list_attributes in your model classes.

Cheers,

Comment: Also, we might have to remove config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict from development.rb

Comment: does the same apply for `config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true`? Because I get the same error.